# I've downloaded android studio 3.0.1 and this message shown to me after the installation

Tags: android

[image]

I've downloaded android studio 3.0.1 and this message shown to me after the installation, gradle project sync failed, basic functionality will not work properly.
10:53 ص Gradle sync failed: CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher
                Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (30s 744ms)

Comment: probably message is telling you truth about `is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. `

Comment: i uninstall in and then re install it again, i still get the same message.

Comment: maybe that's because you didn't read the message?